# inheriting a base flask form that has validation

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a flask form, here is part of the code:

```
class BaseForm(FlaskForm):
    username = TextField('Username')
    email = TextField('Email', [validators.Required('Please enter your email address.'), validators.Length(min=6, message=('Too short for an email address?')), validators.Email(message=('Enter a valid email address.'))
    ])
    password = PasswordField('Password')
    register = SubmitField('Register')

class RegisterForm(BaseForm):
    BaseForm.username
    BaseForm.email
    BaseForm.password
    BaseForm.register
```

When I use the ***code above, the error messages are not rendered***, however, when I use the ***code below the errors are rendered***:

```
class BaseForm(FlaskForm):
    username = TextField('Username')
    email = TextField('Email', [validators.Required('Please enter your email address.'), validators.Length(min=6, message=('Too short for an email address?')), validators.Email(message=('Enter a valid email address.'))
    ])
    password = PasswordField('Password')
    register = SubmitField('Register')

class RegisterForm(BaseForm):
    BaseForm.username
    email = TextField('Email', [validators.Required('Please enter your email address.'), validators.Length(min=6, message=('Too short for an email address?')), validators.Email(message=('Enter a valid email address.'))
    ])
    BaseForm.password
    BaseForm.register
```

So it seems to me that the problem here is that the ***validations are not inherited along with the fields*** or maybe I don't understand. I am trying to reduce the code am writing. **Kindly help me implement the form inheritance I was trying by telling me how I can use my first code** or if it's mission impossible

Comment: [As it stated in a WTForms docs](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/forms.html#form-inheritance) you shouldn't specify inherited fields in a subclassed form.

Answer (score 3):

Your RegisterForm has no new field from BaseForm.
Anyway, don't redefine your fields in a child class. 
Maybe you should start by reading some programmatic language, for exemple in Python, with a particular attention on inheritence.

Just do this:

```
class BaseForm(FlaskForm):
    username = TextField('Username')
    email = TextField('Email', [validators.Required('Please enter your email address.'), validators.Length(min=6, message=('Too short for an email address?')), validators.Email(message=('Enter a valid email address.'))])
    password = PasswordField('Password')

class RegisterForm(BaseForm):
    register = SubmitField('Register')
```

Comment: It has no new field because I removed them while posting the question. In fact, the scenario is that I have many forms: contact form, login form etc. so that is why I was using inheritance.

Comment: Ok but is it working now? What I suggested you should work

Answer (score 1):

```
class BaseForm(Form):
    def __iter__(self):
        token = self.csrf_token
        yield token

        field_names = {token.name}
        for cls in self.__class__.__bases__:
            for field in cls():
                field_name = field.name
                if field_name not in field_names:
                    field_names.add(field_name)
                    yield self[field_name]

        for field_name in self._fields:
            if field_name not in field_names:
                yield self[field_name]

class EmailForm(BaseForm):
    email = EmailField('Email')


class PasswordForm(BaseForm):
    password = PasswordField('Password')


class EmailPasswordForm(EmailForm, PasswordForm):
    pass
```